# PL/SQL -If exists in Table type of varchar2 not working

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using a huge table which loops inside a cursor so i thought rather than querying on each iteration, put the particular data in a Table type and then check data exists inside the loop.

```
declare
 type type_product_list is table of varchar(6);
 product_list type_product_list;
begin

SELECT distinct(PRODUCT_NUMBER) 
    BULK COLLECT INTO product_list
    FROM WEB_PRODUCTS web WHERE some conditions;


    FOR i IN 1..product_list.COUNT LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(product_list(i)); -- This line printing properly.
    END LOOP;

    IF product_list.EXISTS('00029') THEN  -- This condition always fails
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Found');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not Found');   
    END IF;
end;
```

**Output**

00029

00030

00031

00032

..... other data

NOT FOUND

Please help, how can I get the IF block executed.

---

***Update**

Main purpose of this problem is to call a function inside the IF block, and if block itself will be inside a cursor loop which gives dynamic product id in each iteration, i.e. if the product id exists then call that function.

```
begin

SELECT distinct(PRODUCT_NUMBER) 
        BULK COLLECT INTO product_list
        FROM WEB_PRODUCTS web WHERE some conditions;

OPEN cur_cms_scriptdtl();
    LOOP
        FETCH cur_cms_scriptdtl INTO productId, productName;
        EXIT WHEN cur_cms_scriptdtl%notfound;

        IF product_list.EXISTS(productId) THEN  
           -- Function call
        END IF;

END LOOP;
CLOSE cur_cms_scriptdtl;
```

Comment: What is the business problem this is supposed to solve? It seems you are doing in PL/SQL (very inefficiently) something that should be done in plain SQL. Typical XY problem. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Apologies, I updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

After some digging and help from Oracle docs, I was able to get it without FOR LOOP.

The helping angel here is : **member of**

```
BEGIN

SELECT distinct(PRODUCT_NUMBER) 
        BULK COLLECT INTO product_list
        FROM WEB_PRODUCTS web WHERE some conditions;

OPEN cur_cms_scriptdtl();
    LOOP
        FETCH cur_cms_scriptdtl INTO productId, productName;
        EXIT WHEN cur_cms_scriptdtl%notfound;

        IF productId member of product_list THEN
           -- Function call
        END IF;

END LOOP;
CLOSE cur_cms_scriptdtl;
```

Answer (score 1):

In collections, **exists** method receives as parameter an **index**, not a value.

```
    IF product_list(i) = '00029' THEN
```

Try this:

```
DECLARE
    type type_product_list is table of varchar(6);
    product_list type_product_list;
    vFound BOOLEAN := false;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..product_list.COUNT LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(product_list(i));
        IF product_list(i) = '00029' THEN
           vFound := true;
           exit;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;       

    IF vFound THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Found');
    ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line('Not Found');   
    END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Thank for the answer but this if block is already inside a cursor loop so nesting the loops doesnot sound like good idea.

Comment: It is just an example of how to test the values in an IF. Put the IF wherever you need. I think depending on the source of your testing values you could use a IN, or LOOP, implicit cursor, etc.

Comment: @Mohd.Umar please run this code.It should work fine. If it's not..then I think there is some piece of information you have missed mentioning in your query.

Comment: Sorry, its working my data was 5 digits, so was failing.